# Speed up a copmplexy PostGres query with indexes

Tags: postgresql

I have a complexy query with sequelize and postgreSQL and I´d like to speed the response. For now, I don´t have many rows, but It will have.

What indexes do I have to create?

Explain/Analyze

```
"Sort  (cost=24.36..24.36 rows=1 width=2141) (actual time=0.234..0.237 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: ""Message"".""createdAt"""
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=5.55..24.35 rows=1 width=2141) (actual time=0.227..0.229 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5.41..23.81 rows=1 width=1851) (actual time=0.226..0.229 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Join Filter: (""Message"".""contactId"" = contact.id)"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5.41..16.57 rows=1 width=1561) (actual time=0.226..0.228 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                    Join Filter: (""Message"".""ticketId"" = ticket.id)"
"                    Rows Removed by Join Filter: 6"
"                    ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=4.32..8.52 rows=1 width=564) (actual time=0.109..0.115 rows=3 loops=1)"
"                          Hash Cond: ((""quotedMsg"".id)::text = (""Message"".""quotedMsgId"")::text)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on ""Messages"" ""quotedMsg""  (cost=0.00..3.87 rows=87 width=282) (actual time=0.003..0.034 rows=87 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=4.30..4.30 rows=1 width=282) (actual time=0.058..0.058 rows=3 loops=1)"
"                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on ""Messages"" ""Message""  (cost=0.00..4.30 rows=1 width=282) (actual time=0.023..0.053 rows=3 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: (""fromMe"" AND (""messageId"" IS NULL) AND ((""scheduleDate"" <= '2023-07-20 08:56:37.738-03'::timestamp with time zone) OR (""scheduleDate"" IS NULL)) AND ((status)::text = 'pending'::text))"
"                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 84"
"                    ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1.09..8.04 rows=1 width=997) (actual time=0.011..0.035 rows=2 loops=3)"
"                          Hash Cond: (""ticket->contact"".id = ticket.""contactId"")"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on ""Contacts"" ""ticket->contact""  (cost=0.00..6.68 rows=68 width=290) (actual time=0.003..0.016 rows=71 loops=3)"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=1.08..1.08 rows=1 width=707) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=2 loops=1)"
"                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on ""Tickets"" ticket  (cost=0.00..1.08 rows=1 width=707) (actual time=0.009..0.011 rows=2 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: (((status)::text <> 'closed'::text) AND (""tenantId"" = 1) AND (""whatsappId"" = 1) AND ((channel)::text = 'whatsapp'::text))"
"                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 2"
"              ->  Seq Scan on ""Contacts"" contact  (cost=0.00..7.02 rows=17 width=290) (never executed)"
"                    Filter: (((number)::text <> ALL ('{"""",""null""}'::text[])) AND (""tenantId"" = 1))"
"        ->  Index Scan using ""Contacts_pkey"" on ""Contacts"" ""quotedMsg->contact""  (cost=0.14..0.53 rows=1 width=290) (never executed)"
"              Index Cond: (id = ""quotedMsg"".""contactId"")"
"Planning Time: 1.639 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.377 ms"
```

Query:

```
SELECT "Message"."id", "Message"."messageId", "Message"."ack", "Message"."status", "Message"."wabaMediaId", "Message"."read", "Message"."fromMe", "Message"."body", "Message"."mediaUrl", "Message"."mediaType", "Message"."isDeleted", "Message"."createdAt", "Message"."updatedAt", "Message"."quotedMsgId", "Message"."ticketId", "Message"."contactId", "Message"."timestamp", "Message"."userId", "Message"."scheduleDate", "Message"."sendType", "Message"."tenantId", "Message"."idFront", "contact"."id" AS "contact.id", "contact"."name" AS "contact.name", "contact"."number" AS "contact.number", "contact"."email" AS "contact.email", "contact"."profilePicUrl" AS "contact.profilePicUrl", "contact"."pushname" AS "contact.pushname", "contact"."telegramId" AS "contact.telegramId", "contact"."whatsappId" AS "contact.whatsappId", "contact"."messengerId" AS "contact.messengerId", "contact"."instagramPK" AS "contact.instagramPK", "contact"."isUser" AS "contact.isUser", "contact"."isWAContact" AS "contact.isWAContact", "contact"."isGroup" AS "contact.isGroup", "contact"."tenantId" AS "contact.tenantId", "contact"."createdAt" AS "contact.createdAt", "contact"."updatedAt" AS "contact.updatedAt", "ticket"."id" AS "ticket.id", "ticket"."status" AS "ticket.status", "ticket"."unreadMessages" AS "ticket.unreadMessages", "ticket"."lastMessage" AS "ticket.lastMessage", "ticket"."channel" AS "ticket.channel", "ticket"."answered" AS "ticket.answered", "ticket"."isGroup" AS "ticket.isGroup", "ticket"."isActiveDemand" AS "ticket.isActiveDemand", "ticket"."lastInteractionBot" AS "ticket.lastInteractionBot", "ticket"."botRetries" AS "ticket.botRetries", "ticket"."closedAt" AS "ticket.closedAt", "ticket"."lastMessageAt" AS "ticket.lastMessageAt", "ticket"."startedAttendanceAt" AS "ticket.startedAttendanceAt", "ticket"."userId" AS "ticket.userId", "ticket"."contactId" AS "ticket.contactId", "ticket"."whatsappId" AS "ticket.whatsappId", "ticket"."autoReplyId" AS "ticket.autoReplyId", "ticket"."stepAutoReplyId" AS "ticket.stepAutoReplyId", "ticket"."chatFlowId" AS "ticket.chatFlowId", "ticket"."stepChatFlow" AS "ticket.stepChatFlow", "ticket"."queueId" AS "ticket.queueId", "ticket"."tenantId" AS "ticket.tenantId", "ticket"."apiConfig" AS "ticket.apiConfig", "ticket"."createdAt" AS "ticket.createdAt", "ticket"."updatedAt" AS "ticket.updatedAt", "ticket->contact"."id" AS "ticket.contact.id", "ticket->contact"."name" AS "ticket.contact.name", "ticket->contact"."number" AS "ticket.contact.number", "ticket->contact"."email" AS "ticket.contact.email", "ticket->contact"."profilePicUrl" AS "ticket.contact.profilePicUrl", "ticket->contact"."pushname" AS "ticket.contact.pushname", "ticket->contact"."telegramId" AS "ticket.contact.telegramId", "ticket->contact"."whatsappId" AS "ticket.contact.whatsappId", "ticket->contact"."messengerId" AS "ticket.contact.messengerId", "ticket->contact"."instagramPK" AS "ticket.contact.instagramPK", "ticket->contact"."isUser" AS "ticket.contact.isUser", "ticket->contact"."isWAContact" AS "ticket.contact.isWAContact", "ticket->contact"."isGroup" AS "ticket.contact.isGroup", "ticket->contact"."tenantId" AS "ticket.contact.tenantId", "ticket->contact"."createdAt" AS "ticket.contact.createdAt", "ticket->contact"."updatedAt" AS "ticket.contact.updatedAt", "quotedMsg"."id" AS "quotedMsg.id", "quotedMsg"."messageId" AS "quotedMsg.messageId", "quotedMsg"."ack" AS "quotedMsg.ack", "quotedMsg"."status" AS "quotedMsg.status", "quotedMsg"."wabaMediaId" AS "quotedMsg.wabaMediaId", "quotedMsg"."read" AS "quotedMsg.read", "quotedMsg"."fromMe" AS "quotedMsg.fromMe", "quotedMsg"."body" AS "quotedMsg.body", "quotedMsg"."mediaUrl" AS "quotedMsg.mediaUrl", "quotedMsg"."mediaType" AS "quotedMsg.mediaType", "quotedMsg"."isDeleted" AS "quotedMsg.isDeleted", "quotedMsg"."createdAt" AS "quotedMsg.createdAt", "quotedMsg"."updatedAt" AS "quotedMsg.updatedAt", "quotedMsg"."quotedMsgId" AS "quotedMsg.quotedMsgId", "quotedMsg"."ticketId" AS "quotedMsg.ticketId", "quotedMsg"."contactId" AS "quotedMsg.contactId", "quotedMsg"."timestamp" AS "quotedMsg.timestamp", "quotedMsg"."userId" AS "quotedMsg.userId", "quotedMsg"."scheduleDate" AS "quotedMsg.scheduleDate", "quotedMsg"."sendType" AS "quotedMsg.sendType", "quotedMsg"."tenantId" AS "quotedMsg.tenantId", "quotedMsg"."idFront" AS "quotedMsg.idFront", "quotedMsg->contact"."id" AS "quotedMsg.contact.id", "quotedMsg->contact"."name" AS "quotedMsg.contact.name", "quotedMsg->contact"."number" AS "quotedMsg.contact.number", "quotedMsg->contact"."email" AS "quotedMsg.contact.email", "quotedMsg->contact"."profilePicUrl" AS "quotedMsg.contact.profilePicUrl", "quotedMsg->contact"."pushname" AS "quotedMsg.contact.pushname", "quotedMsg->contact"."telegramId" AS "quotedMsg.contact.telegramId", "quotedMsg->contact"."whatsappId" AS "quotedMsg.contact.whatsappId", "quotedMsg->contact"."messengerId" AS "quotedMsg.contact.messengerId", "quotedMsg->contact"."instagramPK" AS "quotedMsg.contact.instagramPK", "quotedMsg->contact"."isUser" AS "quotedMsg.contact.isUser", "quotedMsg->contact"."isWAContact" AS "quotedMsg.contact.isWAContact", "quotedMsg->contact"."isGroup" AS "quotedMsg.contact.isGroup", "quotedMsg->contact"."tenantId" AS "quotedMsg.contact.tenantId", "quotedMsg->contact"."createdAt" AS "quotedMsg.contact.createdAt", 
"quotedMsg->contact"."updatedAt" AS "quotedMsg.contact.updatedAt" FROM "Messages" AS "Message" 
INNER JOIN "Contacts" AS "contact" ON "Message"."contactId" = "contact"."id" 
AND "contact"."tenantId" = 1 AND "contact"."number" NOT IN ('', 'null') 
INNER JOIN "Tickets" AS "ticket" ON "Message"."ticketId" = "ticket"."id" 
AND "ticket"."tenantId" = 1 AND "ticket"."status" != 'closed' 
AND "ticket"."channel" = 'whatsapp' AND "ticket"."whatsappId" = 1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Contacts" AS "ticket->contact" 
   ON "ticket"."contactId" = "ticket->contact"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Messages" AS "quotedMsg" ON "Message"."quotedMsgId" = "quotedMsg"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Contacts" AS "quotedMsg->contact" ON "quotedMsg"."contactId" = "quotedMsg->contact"."id" 
WHERE ("Message"."scheduleDate" <= '2023-07-20 08:56:37.738 -03:00' OR "Message"."scheduleDate" IS NULL) 
AND "Message"."fromMe" = true AND "Message"."messageId" IS NULL AND "Message"."status" = 'pending' 
ORDER BY "Message"."createdAt" ASC;
```

Comment: "Execution Time: 0.377 ms", could you please tell us what you expect? Even a 1000 times faster is not significant for a human being, you're not going to experience any difference.

Comment: Hi, the execution time is fast because I have only some test rows in the tables. But in explain I have seen that Ticket and Messages aren´t using indexes.

Comment: Using an index can be slower, it all depends. This query is lightning fast, not much to optimize. When you have real data, you might get different query plans, you might run into performance issues, and then you start looking for an index strategy. But first you need real data. And a real problem

Comment: Thank you very much, I will expect to have more data.

Comment: It's not just a question of data. It's the data distribution and the statistics that are likely to be very different when you get away from a small set of test data. Load it up with realistic data, then see what the behavior is. You'll be able to make much more educated decisions then.

Comment: You cannot assess performance with just a few sample data. You will have to use realistic amounts of data.